# How to remove mousedown event from elements of child component?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have 2 components: DashboardView and DashboardOrderCard. What I'm trying to do is when I click on the date picker or select from the DashboardOrderCard not to emit the mousedown event. How can I achieve this? Below is the code for the two components.

```
DashboardView.vue 
<div 
    class="dashboard-view"
    v-bind="$attrs"
>
    <div class="pinned-orders">
        <DashboardOrderCard 
            v-for="(order, index) in pinnedOrders"
            :key="order.id"
            :id="'order-' + order.id"
            :order="order"
            @mousedown="displayProgress(order)"
            @unpin-order="unpinOrder(index)"
        />
    </div>
</div>
```

```
DashboardOrderCard.vue
<el-card>
    <div class="body-wrapper">
        <div class="due-date-wrapper">
            <el-date-picker 
                class="date-picker"
                v-model="currentDueDate" 
                format="DD-MM-YYYY"
                :readonly="isCurrentUserSupervisor === false"
            />
        </div>
            <OrderStatusSelect 
                class="status-select"
                v-model:status="currentStatus"
            />
    </div>
</el-card>
```

I am using Vue3 with `<script setup>` and Typescript.

Comment: Why can't you remove `@mousedown="displayProgress(order)"` from the <DashboardOrderCard> template element?

Comment: Because I want to display another component when I click everywhere on the component, except when I click on the date picker or the select.

Comment: use `stopPropagation()` on the event object to keep it from bubbling up to higher level parts of the DOM.

Comment: This is it @DanielBeck. Thank you very much! I should've read the docs better :)

Answer (score 0):

example uses jquery to keep it simple

```
<a href="#a">
   hello <span> click here </span>
</a>
        
 $("a span").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    // parent's event handler doesn't run
  });
    
  $("a").click(function(e){
   alert("anchor click")
  });
```

so

```
    <el-date-picker
        @mousedown="myStopPropagationFunction" 
        class="date-picker"
        v-model="currentDueDate" 
        format="DD-MM-YYYY"
        :readonly="isCurrentUserSupervisor === false"
                      
     />
// or wrap it in a div and define mousedown event on div, if doesn't support
```